# Where can find this braj geet translation?

Tags: krishna-prem

I was listening to a Bhajan by Shri Vinod Agarwal ji - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndUcEwvZ4lw

The bhajan is mostly in Hindi which I understand but he also sings the following which I don't understand completely -

```
सखि ! घर तजूँ , वन तजूँ , नागर -नगर तजूँ ..
ये वंशीवट तट तजूँ , काहू के न लाजि हौं !!
ये गेह तजूँ , देह तजूँ , पर नेह कहो कैसे तजूँ ?
आज सारे राज बीच ऐसे साज सजि हौं !!
यो बावरो भयो है लोक , बावरी कहे मोको !
सखि ! बावरी कहे ते पे मैं काहू ना बरजि हौं !!
कहईया सुनईया तजूँ ,बाप और भैया तजूँ ..
गईया तजूँ , मईया पै कन्हैया नाहिं तजि हौं
```

Does anyone knows who wrote this poem, which language is this and where can I find its translation?

I really like this line `यो बावरो भयो है लोक , बावरी कहे मोको !` which means that the whole world is mad but they call me mad. I don't understand the next line though. That's why I'm looking for translation of the whole thing.

Comment: I fail to understand how this question is relevant for this site? Mind explaining please?

Comment: @Vivikta The forum is about Hinduism and my question is related to Hinduism. What do you fail to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

सखि ! घर तजूँ , वन तजूँ , नागर -नगर तजूँ .. - O friend I can leave my home, my forest, this city and all the people living in this city.

ये वंशीवट तट तजूँ , काहू के न लाजि हौं !! - I can leave the bank of yamuna where lord krishna used to play flute, I will not hesitate or feel ashamed of anyone.

ये गेह तजूँ , देह तजूँ , पर नेह कहो कैसे तजूँ ? - I can leave my shelter, my body but how can I leave my beloved?

आज सारे राज बीच ऐसे साज सजि हौं !! - Today in front of entire city I will accept this.

यो बावरो भयो है लोक , बावरी कहे मोको ! - People have become so much mad that they tell me mad.

सखि ! बावरी कहे ते पे मैं काहू ना बरजि हौं !! - O friend even if they tell me mad I will not get angry on them.

कहईया सुनईया तजूँ ,बाप और भैया तजूँ .. - I can ignore what people are saying about me, I can leave my father and my brother.

गईया तजूँ , मईया पै कन्हैया नाहिं तजि हौं - I can leave my cows and my mother too but I can never ever leave Kanhaiya(Krishna the supreme lord).

Hare Krishna

Comment: धन्यवादः। अत्युत्तमः महोदय।